# set percentage inside the scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, percentage

I have a `scrollview` and I need to set percentage to the elements inside `scrollview` , it seems its not possible, is there any other way to implement this in other way? I need a layout to scroll and need to set percentage for elements inside.

Comment: Percentage of based on what? Screen height? Can you draw a picture to clear this out?

Comment: Are looking for same as weight property?

Comment: @Niko yes, screen height, I have two `linearlayout` on each other , in one which is in under the other I have a `ImageView` and in the `linearlayout` which is on top, at first I want to see image which is set on the `linearlayout` which is under the other, and after that when user scroll the in-front layout ,the information cover the image on background

Comment: @SwapnilSonar what i want to implement is,  I have two linearlayout on each other , in one which is in under the other I have a ImageView and in the linearlayout which is on top, at first I want to see image which is set on the linearlayout which is under the other, and after that when user scroll the in-front layout ,the information cover the image on background

Comment: Can you post image of the start screen and image of the end screen, what you want to achieve when user scrolls?

Comment: @Niko dear Niko I've tried to but i dont have enough points to add image here, I want to implement something close to the application "Etsy" ,the way that it shows each product

Comment: Can you post your xml and some link to same kind of "Etsy" application screen?